# spring data - read only entity based on view - how to get up-to-date data?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I built a jpa-entity on top of a database view.
The @Version field is mapped to the revision of the table the view is set up upon.

However, when the underlying table row changes, I do net get the update in my view-entity.

When I select the table row directly, I see that its revision changed.

How can I force two request against an entity based on an sql-view to use the latest data and not a cached state?

Comment: Can you post some code where you read the entity? And what do you mean by cached? Do you have a second level cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my problem occurs only in test ... when I read-modify-read an entity in the same test method, I have to manually refresh it in between, when I do a rest itest against the application, the latest values are returned ... so nothing to do here